# What is the difference between universal quantifiers and meta-universal quantifiers?

Tags: isabelle, hol, vcg

The universal quantifier  in first-order logic  (the symbol is  ∀) and meta-universal quantifier  in meta-logic (the symbol is ⋀) what is the main difference?
For the following two lemmas, the first example proves successful using universal quantifiers, while the meta-universal quantifiers do not.

```
lemma "∀ x. P x ⟹ P 0"
  apply simp
  done

lemma "⋀ x. P x ⟹ P 0"
  oops
```

[image: Image of my Isabelle code]

Answer (score 4):

Isabelle is a generic framework for interactive theorem proving. Its meta-logic Isabelle/Pure allows to define a broad range of object-logics, one of them being Isabelle/HOL. As you already hinted, the symbol `∀` is Isabelle/HOL's universal quantifier and the symbol `⋀` is Isabelle/Pure's universal quantifier. Also, the symbol `⟹` is Isabelle/Pure's implication. The operator precedence rules state that `⋀` has lower precedence than `⟹`, and `∀` has higher precedence than `⋀` and `⟹`. Therefore `⋀ x. P x ⟹ P 0` is actually parsed as `⋀ x. (P x ⟹ P 0)` (which clearly doesn't hold) instead of `(⋀ x. P x) ⟹ P 0`, so you need to explicitly parenthesize the proposition `⋀ x. P x`. Then, your lemma can be trivially proved using the usual elimination rule for `⋀` in natural deduction as follows:

```
lemma "(⋀ x. P x) ⟹ P 0"
  by (rule meta_spec)
```

In order to try to avoid this kind of nuances, I'd suggest you to adopt the Isabelle/Isar style for stating your lemmas, namely the following:

```
lemma
  assumes "⋀ x. P x"
  shows "P 0"
  using assms by (rule meta_spec)
```

Please refer to [Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021-1/doc/prog-prove.pdf) and [The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021-1/doc/isar-ref.pdf) for more information.